# How to prevent parent layouts rerenders when their child layout changes in react-router-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-devtools

#### Context

I use a nested routes/layout setup in `react-router` (v6.8).

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<BasicLayout />}>
      <Route path="demo" element={<BasicNestedLayout />}>
        <Route path="index" element={<Index />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="topics" element={<Topics />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
```

The user can click `Link` components on `BasicNestedLayout` to switch between the three sub routes (`index`, `about` and `topic`).

Here is a reproducible example: [app](https://react-router-starter-9kwctk.stackblitz.io/demo/index) | [stackblitz editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-9kwctk?file=index.js)

#### Problem

When monitoring the app with React Chrome DevTools, it looks like everything on the page  does rerender when I click on a `Link`. This includes `BasicLayout`, which contains just the `App Header` and is the parent of  `BasicNestedLayout` where the `Link` and its dependent content lives. All components are highlighted (devtools option = Highlight updates when components render).

[image]

A quick search on StackOverflow reveals that this was already a challenge in `react-router` v4/5, but the accepted answers suggest to switch route props from `component=` to `render=`, which have both been replaced by `element=` in v6 ([doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element)).

How can one prevent the rerender of `BasicLayout` when nothing has changed apart from its children?

Alternatively, is it possible that the React Dev Tools is wrong? I noticed that the `useEffect` hooks, written without dependencies to run at each rerender, don't seem to print their `console.log()` in the Console more than once.

---

Related but still different questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820009/how-to-prevent-layout-loader-in-react-router-6-from-being-called-multiple-times), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816329/avoid-re-rendering-of-parent-components-with-react-router-dom-v6-nested-routes), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629127/react-router-v6-re-renders-on-route-change)

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are seeing here? What are the exact steps to reproduce the issue you describe? I don't see more than one set of console logs, so the layout components aren't rerendering. I think you might be conflating repainting the view with React component rerendering. Compounding the confusion is that it seems stackblitz is *also* a react app, so when selecting "Highlight updates when components render" it seems it displays when that app is also triggering repaints.

Comment: Generally you should just let React rerender when React thinks it should rerender, it's optimized quite well for 60fps performance. Only look to optimize if you've an actual measured/audited performance issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. I tried to improve the question by adding a GIF showing the ReactDevTools highlights. I agree that I am indeed confused: according to its label, the devtools highlights "rerenders", which for me should trigger the `console.logs`. Regarding Stackblitz, I think that, if you run the app in a dedicated tab, you get the same behavior as I have on the real app.

Comment: The console logs in the `useEffect` hook programmatically prove the component didn't rerender. I don't suspect there is any issue with the React code. At this point I'd say it's something in the React dev-tool that is misleading or incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for helping me stop question my sanity. Further research online seem to show that people have encountered similar issues with the DevTool when using library like redux/mobx. Do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: Perhaps. It certainly doesn't appear to be answerable or on-topic for SO if it's an issue with the browser extension.

Comment: use `memo` function to avoid re-renders components which are already rendered

Answer (score 0):

So while the actual outer layer of this component is not re-rendering, the links themselves are rerendering because the context of the route has changed:

[image]

You're also seeing outlines on the rest of the components because React Router has a lot of outer elements that do rerender:

[image]

I'm running into this now doing a tech talk on rendering for my company.